# list appending to last element of collapsible set

Tags: jquery

I am tying to create dynamic collapsible set and to each set I am adding dynamic listview.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {

        $.each(results.rows,function(index){ 
           var row = results.rows.item(index);
           var list=$('#List').append('<li><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+'</h3><p class="ui-li-">'+row['data']+'</p></li>');

           var div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right"><h3>'+row["data"]+'</h3></div>';

           $(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]').end().trigger("create");
           $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});

        });         
     }
```

But the dynamic listview is appending only to last collapsible element and not able to append to others. What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: This is jquery mobile right? If yes you should have added it in the tags section. Moreover I can't understand you want to accomplish. Maybe a jsfiddle would be a good idea

Comment: The "var list" and "$(list)" usage looks suspicious as the 1st is a JS local variable redefined at each loop, and the 2nd is a JQuery object refering to the 1st. At each loop, list is growing and the expected result in the parent div from rows, a, b, c could be something like a, a, b, a, b, c. Could you join an exemple of what you get and what you want ?